# Div doesnt shows up when i hover a link or an icon

Tags: html, css

In my site header, i have a link, and inside this link, a cart ikon.

My problem is, that if i hover this link, the .cart_hover div wont show up. Why? What am i doing wrong? I also tryed with display, not just visibility, but nothing happend.

[Here you can take a look at the demo site](https://projektar.hu/)

In my style.css file, i have this row for the hover.

```
.header_kosar_link:hover > .cart_hover {visibility: visible;}
```

**Code Updated:**

If the webshop cart is empty, the hover is working. But if i add some products to the cart, there is no hover. Why?

```
<div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end align-items-center header_div">
            <a href="<?php echo $host; ?>/kosar" title="Kosár" class="header_kosar_link d-flex align-items-center">
                <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fejlec_kosar_ikon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
                <span id="header_kosar_text" class="header_kosar_text"></span>
                <div class="cart_hover">
                    <div class="cart_hover_triangle"></div>
                    <span class="order_page_cart_title">Kosár tartalma</span>
                    <?php
                    if(!$cart->isEmpty())
                    {
                        show_products_in_cart_header();
                    }
                    else    
                    {
                        echo '<span class="cart_totalitem">A kosár üres.</span>';
                    }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Please post the full code

Answer (score 0):

```
.header_kosar_link:hover > .cart_hover {visibility: visible;}
```

Above css not working since .cart_hover is not direct child of .header_kosar_link

You will have to change the way you placed .cart_hover and use [sibling selector](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_combinators.asp)

```
     <div class="col-md-2 d-flex justify-content-center justify-content-md-end align-items-center header_div">
   <a href="https://projektar.hu/kosar" title="Kosár" class="header_kosar_link d-flex align-items-center">
      <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fejlec_kosar_ikon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span id="header_kosar_text" class="header_kosar_text">0</span>
   </a>
   <div class="clearfix"></div>
   <div class="cart_hover">
      <div class="cart_hover_triangle"></div>
      <span class="order_page_cart_title">Kosár tartalma</span>
      <span class="cart_totalitem">A kosár üres.</span>
   </div>
</div>

    a.header_kosar_link:hover ~ .cart_hover {
        visibility: visible;
    }
```

Comment: Hi! I changed the code to this. But, if it is no item in the cart, the hover works. If i add some item to the cart, it wont work. You can try it on the link.

Answer (score 0):

**You have to markup like this format.**

```
 <div class="header_kosar_link">

      <i class="fa fa-shopping-basket fejlec_kosar_ikon" aria-hidden="true"></i>
      <span id="header_kosar_text" class="header_kosar_text">0</span>

    <div class="cart_hover">
      <div class="cart_hover_triangle"></div>
      <span class="order_page_cart_title">Kosár tartalma</span>
      <span class="cart_totalitem">A kosár üres.</span>  
    </div>

</div>
```

Then your hover will work...Cause its work based on parent div..I hope you will get my point.